# NHibernate C# inner join n+1

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Here is my simple С# code:

```
var chests = _session.CreateCriteria<GameCharacterChest>()
    .CreateAlias("GameCharacterEquipments", "equip", JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("GameCharacterId", characterId))
    .List<GameCharacterChest>();

foreach (var chest in chests)
{
    var equip = chest.GameCharacterEquipments.FirstOrNull();
    if (equip != null)
    {
        var slot = (equip as GameCharacterEquipment).GameCharacterSlotTypeId;
    } 
}
```

In `foreach` cycle NHibernate sends SQL query to my DB. Why? information about `GameCharacterEquipment` already requested in first query by inner join.
I have fluent map.

Comment: Please add some domain model classes and mapping. This will result in better answer as there are less to guess from.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
.SetFetchMode("GameCharacterEquipments", FetchMode.Join)
```

or

```
.SetFetchMode("GameCharacterEquipments", FetchMode.Eager)
```

between the various calls (after the `CreateAlias`)

You probably have a lazy relationship defined on the `GameCharacterEquipments`.

Comment: nope. This not work. Everything goes fine when i use "left join" instead of "inner join". But, I need here "inner join".

Comment: @nikashitsa Perhaps there are other lazy tables. The best thing you can do is run the SQL Server Profiler and watch what queries are being generated.

Comment: Here is the SQL queries.

`SELECT ... FROM game_character_chest this_ inner join game_character_equipment equip1_ on this_.id=equip1_.game_character_chest_id WHERE this_.game_character_id = ?

SELECT ... FROM game_character_equipment gamecharac0_ WHERE gamecharac0_.game_character_chest_id=?`

looks ok.

Comment: @nikashitsa So it's redoing a query for some data it already has... I don't know why. You should check the `FirstOrNull` function... It's non-standard.